# Jquery: On Click show submenu and hide any other one that's open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a classic responsive menu with menus and submenus, i'm pretty new to Jquery so i'm having trouble figuring out how to hide a previous submenu when another one needs to be shown.

[Here's the Pencode](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gwbdbN)

This is the HTML:

```
<nav class="products">
    <ul>
        <li class="brown link-menu"><a href="#">wine essentials</a>
            <div class="sub-menu">
                <div class="content-sub-menu">
                    <ul class="sub-menu-list">
                        <li class="link-subcat"><a href="#" class="menu-subcat-link">standard</a></li>
                        <li class="link-subcat"><a href="#" class="menu-subcat-link">premium</a></li>
                        <li class="link-subcat"><a href="#" class="menu-subcat-link">super premium</a></li>
                        <li class="link-subcat"><a href="#" class="menu-subcat-link">ultra premium</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="pink link-menu"><a href="#">wine selective & prestige</a>
            <div class="sub-menu">
                <div class="content-sub-menu">
                    <ul class="sub-menu-list">
                        <li class="link-subcat"><a href="#" class="menu-subcat-link">standard</a></li>
                        <li class="link-subcat"><a href="#" class="menu-subcat-link">premium</a></li>
                        <li class="link-subcat"><a href="#" class="menu-subcat-link">super premium</a></li>
                        <li class="link-subcat"><a href="#" class="menu-subcat-link">ultra premium</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="green link-menu"><a href="#">master distillers</a>
            <div class="sub-menu">
                <div class="content-sub-menu">
                    <ul class="sub-menu-list">
                        <li class="link-subcat"><a href="#" class="menu-subcat-link">standard</a></li>
                        <li class="link-subcat"><a href="#" class="menu-subcat-link">premium</a></li>
                        <li class="link-subcat"><a href="#" class="menu-subcat-link">super premium</a></li>
                        <li class="link-subcat"><a href="#" class="menu-subcat-link">ultra premium</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is the SCSS:

```
nav.products {
  ul {
    li.brown {
      border-left: 10px solid #a09484;
    }
    li.pink {
      border-left: 10px solid #9d7b8c;
    }
    li.green {
      border-left: 10px solid #558d80;
    }
    li {
      border-bottom: none;
      padding: 1em 0;
      margin-bottom: .2em;
      a {} .sub-menu {
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        .content-sub-menu {
          -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
          -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
          -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
          transform: translateY(-100%);
          -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
          -o-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
          transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
          ul.sub-menu-list {
            padding-left: 1em;
            li {
              font-size: 1em;
              margin-bottom: 0;
              a {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
      &.current {
        .content-sub-menu {
          -moz-transform: translateY(0%);
          -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
          -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
          transform: translateY(0%);
        }
        /*DROPDOWNS*/
        .sub-menu {
          height: 100%;
        }
        /*DROPDOWNS END*/
      }
    }
  }
}
nav.products ul li.current .sub-menu {
  height: 100%;
}
```

And i'm using this script to show the submenus:

```
$('.products ul li').click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('current');
});
```

Comment: try with `$('.products ul li').click(function(e) {
          $('.products ul li.current').toggleClass('current');
          $(this).toggleClass('current');
        });`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to hide previously opened sub-menus, you would need to remove their "current" class.

```
$('.products ul li').click(function(e) {
   $('.products ul li').not($(this)).removeClass('current');

  $(this).toggleClass('current');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.products ul li').click(function(e) {
   $('.current').removeClass('.current');
   $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

try the above. This way it will find any current class in the page. remove it and add the class to the current element.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy, just remove the 'current' class from all menu items first, then do the toggle.

```
$('.products ul li').click(function(e) {
  $('.products ul li').removeClass('current');
  $(this).toggleClass('current');
});
```

Here is a working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NRPLRN

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `.current` class from `li`, before `toggling` the `class`.

```
$('.products ul li').click(function(e) {
     $('.products ul li.current').removeClass('current');
     $(this).toggleClass('current');
});
```

## [Updated PEN](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/mAyGON)

Comment: Why to use **toggleClass** instead of **addClass**? in this case, I think that **addClass** is better, because faster than **toggleClass**.